# SFrame: replacing of specific rows in the column

Tags: python-2.7

Sorry, I have probably some simple question.
I have SFrame looks like this:

```
A B C
0 1 2
0 2 3
1 2 3
1 3 4
2 3 1
2 3 3
. . .
```

Also I have another SFrame, looks like this:

```
A B C
0 1 4
0 2 5
```

I want replace SFrame with the similar A & B values, but with new C values.

```
A B C
0 1 4
0 2 5
1 2 3
1 3 4
2 3 1
2 3 3
. . .
```

It could be the all columns in the firstSFrame, but also just one column (SArray).

I try it with the next prompt:

```
sfr['C'][sfr['A']==0] = sfr2['C']
```

or just

```
sfr[sfr['A']==0] = sfr2
```

but got next error message:

```
TypeError: 'SArray' object does not support item assignment
```

Anyway, When I replace the SArray C from the similar length, this solution is worked.... The problem is in the different lengths of SFrames...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, I found someself a simple solution.
I create a list from all values, which I want replace in the first SFrame. Then convert this list to SArray and add it as a new column. (the number of columns is not important for me)...